# Is there a source to find a list of symbols?

Tags: finance, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance, google-finance

I'm using the data of alpha vantage for a stock market analysis site. But I cannot find a complete list of symbols available ( to be used in a selection drop down ).

Comment: @user3666197 What are you talking about??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a list of US-traded stock symbols, the best source to find such information is from [Nasdaq](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx), you can write a small utility to parse the downloaded csv to get the stock symbols.

Comment: Nasdaq webpage only provides the list of symbols of NASDAQ NYSE and AMEX.

I found this website richer in symbols: http://www.eoddata.com


It includes the previous three and others, for example HKEX (hong kong exchnge). but this also isn't exhaustive.

Comment: Yahoo Finance symbols work for Canadian stocks if you are interested in those. eg. SU.TO

Comment: I got a CSV with all listed stocks from https://plextock.com/us-symbols?utm_source=so